# netty receive large buffer

Tags: netty

I got some troubles when I received a buffer with that 65535 bytes.
My buffer is composed with a header and a body. I got from the header the body length.
I got the example from netty web site.

I tried change receive size of netty without result.

```
_bootstrap.setOption("writeBufferHighWaterMark", 10 * 64 * 1024);
_bootstrap.setOption("sendBufferSize", 1048576); 
_bootstrap.setOption("receiveBufferSize", 1048576);
_bootstrap.setOption("tcpNoDelay", true);
```

Thank for help

Answer (score 0):

Frequently, the operating system places limits on the socket buffer sizes, so you may need to tweak your settings to get buffers that large.

Check this [tutorial](http://seeallhearall.blogspot.com/2012/06/netty-tutorial-part-15-on-channel.html) and search for the phrase **"Network Kernel Tuning"**.

Also, [this](http://fasterdata.es.net/host-tuning/) guide outlines how to tweak these limits on different operating systems.